# What is the ruling in badminton when the shuttlecock (birdie) rests on the top of the net?

Tags: rules, badminton

During badminton matches, in very rare circumstances, the shuttlecock (birdie) will fall to rest on the top of the net.  I'm not referring to when the shuttlecock gets stuck in the mesh of the net; I'm referring to when the shuttlecock literally lands *- feathers down -* on the top edge of the net, and continues to rest there without further movement.

This is exceptionally rare, but when it happens, it is usually the result of a lob play that is initiated close to the net and is performed with very low velocity and minimal spin.

Here is a link to video of a great example of this occurring:
https://www.viewpure.com/sXls9PPr54Q

What is the correct ruling when this happens, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shuttle stuck on top of the net is a fault during service and a let otherwise, according to the [Laws of Badminton](https://extranet.bwfbadminton.com/docs/document-system/81/1466/1470/Section%204.1%20-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton.pdf):

> §13.2.1 It shall be a fault if in service the shuttle is caught on the net and remains suspended on its top.

> §14.2.3.1 It shall be a let if after the service is returned, the shuttle is
> caught on the net and remains suspended on its top.